# Separate column by string patterns

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, stringr, tibble

I have the following example:

```
structure(list(value = c("./LRoot_1/LClass_copepodo", "./LRoot_1/LClass_shadow", 
"./LRoot_2/LClass_bolha", "./LRoot_2/LClass_cladocera")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I would to like separate this in two columns, the first column with the names that are between bars "/" and the second column with the name after "LClass_"

Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

We could use `extract` - capture (`(...)`) the substrings that we needed while remove the rest of characters i.e, below regex matches the `.` (`\\.`- metacharacter that matches any character thus escaped), followed by the `/`, then capture the one or more (`+`) characters that are not a `/` (`[^/]`) as the first capture group, followed by matching the 'LCass_' substring and then capture the rest of characters (`.*`) as second capture group

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, value, into = c("first", "second"),
     "\\./([^/]+)/LClass_(.*)", remove = FALSE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  value                      first   second   
  <chr>                      <chr>   <chr>    
1 ./LRoot_1/LClass_copepodo  LRoot_1 copepodo 
2 ./LRoot_1/LClass_shadow    LRoot_1 shadow   
3 ./LRoot_2/LClass_bolha     LRoot_2 bolha    
4 ./LRoot_2/LClass_cladocera LRoot_2 cladocera
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative option using `separate` and `word`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  separate(col = value, into = c("first", "second"), sep = "/(?=LClass)") %>% 
  mutate(first = word(first, 2, sep = "/"),
         second = word(second, 2, sep = "_"))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  first   second   
  <chr>   <chr>    
1 LRoot_1 copepodo 
2 LRoot_1 shadow   
3 LRoot_2 bolha    
4 LRoot_2 cladocera
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `separate()` the column at `/` then remove the pattern `LClass_` via `mutate()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>% 
  separate(col = value, into = c(NA, 'a', 'b'), sep = '/', remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(
    b = gsub(pattern = 'LClass_', replacement = '', x = b)
  )
```

```r
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   value                      a       b        
#>   <chr>                      <chr>   <chr>    
#> 1 ./LRoot_1/LClass_copepodo  LRoot_1 copepodo 
#> 2 ./LRoot_1/LClass_shadow    LRoot_1 shadow   
#> 3 ./LRoot_2/LClass_bolha     LRoot_2 bolha    
#> 4 ./LRoot_2/LClass_cladocera LRoot_2 cladocera
```